# Django Models - How to save the result of a function in the database

Tags: python, django, database, function, django-models

i have a little speed problem in my django web page.
I'm making a website that picks prices of amazon articles. My problem is that i used lxml for crawling the html data and that function repeats every time i reload the page, and a page with 6 articles takes like 15 seconds to load. This is my function:

```
def price(self):
    if self.amazon_url:
        url = self.amazon_url
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        code = html.fromstring(source_code.text)
        prices = code.xpath('//span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()')
        eur = prices[0].replace("EUR ", "")
        nospace = eur.replace(" ", "")
        nodown = nospace.replace("\n", "")
        end = nodown.replace(",", ".")
        return float(end)
    else:
        return 0
```

ok, now, this function is inside my class in django models and also is what i think makes the page load so slow. The question is: once i have crawled the price, can i store it in my sql database so i don't have to use this function everytime i reload the page?
I'm planning to add mode products in my database, so i would like to use this function only one time for every product and then store the price in my database.
Hope you can help me, i'm not so good with python so please try to expla it in in simple words thanks

Comment: Put a price field on your model and save the price your crawled into it, you may also add a datetimefield which stores the time when the price was saved. You may crawl the price only once a day or so.

Comment: the problem is that i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests i decided to use the AmazonProductAPI and it seems to work fine